# Найти наибольшее значение в списке словарей, если ключ одинаковый

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Есть такой список, содержащий словари:

```
list_param = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff_rate': Decimal('3.00')}, {'company': 'Apple', 'tariff_rate': Decimal('4.00')}, {'company': 'Apple', 'tariff_rate': Decimal('3.00')}]
```

Причем, компаний может быть много разных, нужно для одинаковых найти наибольший коэффициент.

Имею следующее:

```
 def comparison_rate(d, x):
    k = x['company']
    if k in d:
        d[k]['tariff_rate'] = max(x['tariff_rate'] for k in d)
    else:
        d[k] = x
    return d

tariff = reduce(comparison_rate, list_param, {}).values()
```

Отдает просто самый последний словарь, в данном случае с коэффициентом 3.0

```
print(tariff)
[{'tariff_rate': Decimal('3.00'), 'company': 'Apple'}]
```

Python 3.5. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
d[k]['tariff_rate'] = max(x['tariff_rate'] for k in d)
```

Я не очень понял, что вы хотели тут сделать, но выражение в скобках всегда будет содержать некоторое количество одинаковых элементов. Соответственно, брать максимум от этого нет никакого смысла.

Код начнёт работать, если заменить эту строку на что-то вроде:

```
d[k]['tariff_rate'] = max(d[k]['tariff_rate'], x['tariff_rate'])
```

Но, вообще, имхо, вы переусложнили. Я бы решал эту задачу так:

```
srt = sorted(list_param, key=lambda d: d['tariff_rate'])

tariff = {}
for dct in srt:
  tariff.update({dct['company']: dct['tariff_rate']})

print(tariff)
```

UPD: Что касается вопроса в комментариях.

Самый простой способ - заменить строку внутри цикла на такую:

```
tariff.update({dct['company']: dct})
```

В этом случае в словаре-результате у вас для каждой компании будет лежать полностью тот словарик из исходного списка, в котором тариф по этой компании был максимален.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

`{'Apple': {'company': 'Apple', 'tariff_rate': Decimal('4.00'), 'sum': 100}}`

Соответственно, после этого вы сможете уже по названию параметра доставать из этого словаря хоть тариф, хоть сумму, хоть какой-то другой показатель, если он был в исходных данных:

`tariff['Apple']['sum']`

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажите еще, если у меня в словаре, кроме 'company' и 'tariff_rate' ещё скажем 'sum' есть. Как мне у этого максимального коэффициента, взять этот соседний элемент - 'sum'?

Comment: @Fill, дописал в ответ.

Comment: по названию достать можно конечно, но что если я заранее не знаю у какой компании максимальный коэффициент? Я так понимаю нужно снова пройтись по словарю, который мы апдейтили, найти у кого max, вытащить 'sum' . 
То есть сначала нашли максимальный коэф. для каждой компании, потом среди них :)

Comment: Дописал так:
`m = max(tariff, key=lambda i: tariff[i]['tariff_rate'])`
`print(tariff[m]['sum'])`